# Directory Group Issue?

Tags: linux, permissions, user-accounts

I have a directory that needs to be owned by nginx user and I need to access it via other users in order to add/edit/delete files in it.

So I created a group called www and added both then chgrp -R on the directory. However I am still getting a "unavailable to access no permissions" sort of error in my SSH/SCP/what ever you want to call Mac's Transmit.

```
ls -a output
drwxr----- 3 nginx www 4096 Jul 17 23:56 nginx
```

Any help?

Answer (score 1):

Directories need execute permissions (`x`) in order to be traversed. Add `g+x`.